# Rendering bug in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, animation, twitter-bootstrap

Stumbled upon a weird Chrome-only rendering behavior for select-boxes: Select one option and during rendering Chrome will spit out lines that seems to start from the select-boxes.

When setting:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

as opposed to

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button
```

the problem ceases to exist.

Here's a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SA4eZ/) (tested using Chrome 18).

Has anyone come across anything similar?

Comment: you should report that as a Chrome bug, not as a question here.

Comment: I have tried your example in Chrome 18.0.1025.168m (Windows) and it appears to render OK for me?

Comment: Happening in Chrome 18.0.1025.168 on OS X 10.7.3. It's *not* happening in Chrome 20.0.1130.1, though, so perhaps it's been fixed?

Comment: Maybe an Mac-only problem then. Wanted to post here first before posting as Chrome bug.

Comment: FYI. This problem was resolved with the automatic update to Chrome 19.

Comment: @ricardo if resolved you should post the answer and accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Google Chrome 18 related bug and was patched in version 19.